# How to inject class with type constraint in .NET DI?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use [generic type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) to pass which implementation of interface to use in the handler. The decision must be made in controller (different controllers will use same handler but will pass different implementations of service to handler)

Handler:

```
    public class Core<T> : ICore<T> where T: class, IMessengerCommunicationService
    {
        private T _messengerService;

        public Core(
            T messengerCommunicationService)
        {
            _messengerService = messengerCommunicationService;
        }

        public async Task Process(Update update)
        {
             ...
             await _messengerService.SendMessage(user.Id, "Ok!");
             ...
        }
...
```

Handler interface:

```
    public interface ICore<T> where T: class, IMessengerCommunicationService
    {
        Task Process(Update update);
    }
```

IMessengerCommunicationService has several implementations.

```
    public interface IMessengerCommunicationService
    {
        Task SendMessage(long userId, string text);
    }
```

That's how I inject it (`TelegramBotAdapter` is an implementation of `IMessengerCommunicationService`):

```
            services.AddScoped<IMessengerCommunicationService, TelegramBotAdapter>();

            services.AddScoped<ICore<IMessengerCommunicationService>, Core<IMessengerCommunicationService>>();
```

Finally, specifying which implementation I want to use in a controller:

```
    public class TelegramController : ControllerBase
    {
        public readonly ICore<TelegramBotAdapter> _core;

        public TelegramController(
here -->    ICore<TelegramBotAdapter> core)
        {
            _core = core;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Update([FromBody] Update update)
        {
            _core.Process(update);
            return Ok();
        }
```

I'm getting following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Core.ICore`1[Adapters.TelegramBotAdapter]' while attempting to activate 'WebHookGate.Controllers.TelegramController'.
```

Didn't I activated TelegramBotAdapter?
Can't I do injections like that? How to do it properly?

Comment: no , `services.AddScoped<IMessengerCommunicationService, TelegramBotAdapter>();` will not work with `Core.ICore<Adapters.TelegramBotAdapter>` like that, you'll have to do something like `services.AddScoped<ICore<IMessengerCommunicationService>, Core<TelegramBotAdapter>>();`. you definitely misunderstood type parameters

Comment: You only need the following two services declarations `services.AddScoped<TelegramBotAdapter>();` and `services.AddScoped(typeof(ICore<>), typeof(Core<>));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have declared services incorrectly.
Instead of

```
services.AddScoped<IMessengerCommunicationService, TelegramBotAdapter>();
services.AddScoped<ICore<IMessengerCommunicationService>, Core<IMessengerCommunicationService>>();
```

I should to declare them that way:

```
services.AddScoped<TelegramBotAdapter>();
services.AddScoped(typeof(ICore<>), typeof(Core<>));
```

Thanks to @Kalten.